# Cannot install ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04

Why am I having so many problems with the disc installation ubuntu 14.04.2?
I am installing on a new disc with 497Gb free space. I created a / partition then a swap partition of 9Gb in EXT4. There is another disk in the system which contains windows 7 but I am not dual booting, will use bios to select boot disk. The live CD runs fine and I can go on the internet via Firefox.

Firstly when I go to install, the internet is not available, even though it is available from the live CD. When I go to install, the installation tells me there is a problem finding a file on the CD and I have to abort.

Answer (score 0):

try to format a partition with Windows 7, if you don't need them, and create / partition on this space. And try to create SWAP partition, /home partition behind

Comment: Thanks. So do I create an ntfs partition with W7? then create/partition with the ubuntu disc with SWAP followed by /home.

Comment: If you want to delete W7 and use Ubuntu only, you can delete partition with windows from life-CD using Gparted. Next, you start installation and create partitions

Comment: Ok I got it installed. I reformatted the drive to ntfs then partitioned it after ubuntu started it's installation. This worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing ubuntu 14.04 in seperate Drive. so, where is boot loader install that is cause your problem.

You can first temp. remove windows 7 Drive and **Fresh install ubuntu 14.04LTS in seperate Disk/Drive**.
In 1 Disk you have windows and another one currently installed ubuntu.

*Now you can use **BIOS** to select which Drive should be boot or which OS will load.*

Comment: Thanks, what you are saying is logical, I should have done this from the beginning. Windows installations are the same - can have only one drive present to install on. However it seemed to work OK as above.